# Need suggestions to fit unknown functions

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions

I've generated these curves from a set of data and would like to fit them to come up with a model for a program I'm writing. Can anyone suggest functions that might approximate my curves?
I'm a physicist so I immediately saw similarities with Planck's law for black body radiation for the blue curve (which fits well for positive values) and the Lennard-Jones potential for the red curve (although this doesn't come above zero after the initial trench)

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

[raw data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7of6tikpdzsduol/rawSData_FW.ods)

[image: functions to be fit]

Comment: The little problem is that reading the values from your graphs is rather difficult. There are tons of expressions that give those general shapes but if you want some decent quantitative approximations, posting the data tables would be much more useful. So, could you add the numerical data you want to interpolate to the post?

Comment: Suggestions is all I really want, I was going to fit them using least-square regression and see what worked. I suppose I can post the data if you think it'll help.

Comment: You see, any 3 negative powers form a system sufficient to reproduce the dive, the dip, the rebound, and the decay by taking an appropriate linear combination. However, the quantitative fit may be extremely poor if you choose wrong powers or if, say, the decay at infinity is not power at all but exponential. So, yes, seeing the data will help :-).

Comment: OK, edited into question.
This isn't a final data set, just the first pass on a sample. It'd help me a great deal if you could explain your process too.

Comment: Any new data yet? As I said, I do not even want to try to guess the behavior of the red curve near $0$ from just one significant point and that is the most problematic place to fit...

Answer (score 1):

OK, the blue curve is
$$
B(x)=\frac{x^2-0.015^2}{30x^2[1+(x/0.07)^4]}
$$
The parameters may be not exactly optimal, but, frankly  speaking, with as much noise in the data as you gave me, I didn't see any point in trying to fit them any better. Once you produce something that has less crazy jumps from one point to another (especially near the end where the values get smaller), I can try to get a better fit. I am pretty sure about the general kind of the expression up to minor tweaks, which are meaningless to discuss without getting minimally decent experimental precision first.

See if this helps. I'll try the red curve next :-)

**Edit:**

The red curve may possibly be
$$
R(y)=\int_y^\infty\frac{0.34(x-0.015)(x-0.16)}{x^2[1+(x/0.18)^4]}\,dx
$$
except this gives the value at $0.005$ ten times less than in your table (whether your number, as recorded, is a misprint with one head zero missing or not I cannot tell; the information near $0$ is severely insufficient).

The formula 
$$
R(y)=\int_y^\infty\frac{0.27(x^2-0.0155^2)(x-0.16)}{x^3[1+(x/0.185)^4]}\,dx
$$
would fit all data almost perfectly, but cubic polynomial in the numerator seems to be an overkill (after all, everything can be approximated by rational functions if the degree is high enough).

My current guess is that, in general, you have some (radial?) force field given by 
$$
F(r)=A\frac{(r-u)(r-v)}{r^2[1+(r/w)^4]}
$$
or something like that and the blue curve is the force while the red curve is the potential.

If my assumption is correct, the only thing that remains to discuss is how to do the best fit of parameters for noisy data and what measurements to make (all your points for the red curve beyond $0.65$ are total gibberish: your equipment cannot even make its mind about whether the value is positive or negative, so it makes no sense to look there at all, while I would really love smaller steps and more values near $0$). If not, let me know what is really going on :-).

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. The blue line is fantastic, although I'm afraid you've confused me with the red line; specifically, why it's a function of y.

What I'm measuring is the length of quiet (blue) and loud (red) spells in audio files. I have a sample of voice files and a sample of sound effects files. I'm treating the sound effects as a random noise which I'm then subtracting from the voice files to leave the specific features of a voice file. The fact that you've come up with a general solution and what you've inferred from the data is very interesting to me.

Comment: @FlyingWeagle OK, I'll reconsider the red one :-). I cannot say I liked the result myself. However, I need more data because, as I said, it is completely impossible to say anything certain about the behavior near $0$ from just one point. Can you post some more sets of values with smaller steps near $0$? Then I'll try to do something better for the red line.

Comment: I think it makes sense that they're related functions and even if they aren't, a good guess is better than what I had to begin with. I'll see about increasing the resolution but I'm going to be running low on data points to determine loud vs quiet so the data may end up being meaningless. I can't get a zero value as there can't be a pause or burst of length zero. Also, given how the data is generated, I guess an assumption of +/- infinity might make sense. Can you change the R(y) functions into a straight f(x) form in the meantime?